# React Native / React Navigation Performance: Best practice for storing/passing data for list views?

Tags: performance, react-native, datastore, react-navigation

> Preface: I'd like to hold off on implementing a Redux store quite yet
>   as it seems fairly in depth and I'm not sure if I need it quite yet (also, the
>   project scope/budget is what it is).

I'm using react navigation (a stack navigator) and I'm trying to find out what the best practice to preload/store data for list views (~40 items in my case)? I've got a main home screen, and the 2nd screen the user navigates to is a list view (FlatList). The data for the FlatList is coming from a JSON object in a local file. If I import the data in the screen component like so:

```
import someData from '../data/someData'
```

it doesn't result in the instant/zero latency loading that I'm looking for. That is - navigating without the data import is instant - but navigating and importing that data directly in the screen file causes latency in-between touching to navigate and the app actually starting the navigation animation.

I'd imagine that I should be loading the data beforehand, ideally when the app first loads, and then access it from some global variable - OR passing it along as a prop in the navigator? Then I could access it with this.props.data in the screen component?

I'm not taking any data from the user - the app is purely informational, so I don't think AsyncStorage is the answer either? (although I could be wrong, it just seems like every asyc storage tutorial I see is about user input).

Any insight onto this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you'd save a lot of potential hassle and fiddling if you just went ahead with Redux. I've just done something very similar and found that implanting redux was not as tedious as I first thought. Alternatively yes, you can pass your data in via props.

Comment: Got it @sooper, thanks for the advice. I need to look up how to pass data with props using React Navigation...

Comment: Np. Performance-wise redux would keep your data in its store and you wouldn't have to import every time.

Answer (score 0):

I was going down the completely wrong rabbit hole. There is nothing wrong with importing your data per screen. I was running Expo in development mode!